# Which of the direction field belong to homogeneous equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

A homogeneous differential equation is a differential equation of the form
$$y'=f(\frac{y}{t})$$

By letting $y'=0$, we can solve for $f(\frac{y}{t})=0$.

This gives us $y = a\cdot t$ for some constant $a$.

I can conclude that, the line segments in the direction field that has $0$ slope forms a line.

However, using this approach does not give me the right answer.

Can you share your method in approaching this question.

Note: There are more than one correct choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slope of the direction field at a point $(t,y)$ is $f(y/t)$. Points in lines $y/t=a$ have the same slope.Looking at the pictures, (c) is a clear candidate, and although it is hard to tell, maybe also (a).

Comment: Same slope meaning it can be non-zero? Why non-zero? Can you point out the mistake in my reasoning posted above?

Comment: $y'=0$ will give you the horizontal "isoclines", which in fact lie on a straight line through the origin. But you must look at the whole direction field. That is, not only to $y'=0$, but to $y'=\text{constant}$.

Comment: $y' = \text{constant}$ $\implies f(y/t) = \text{constant}$

But $\frac{y}{t} = f^{-1}(\text{constant})$ only applies if $f$ is bijective.

Can you explain in more detail please.

Comment: If $f$ is not bijective, them $f(y/t)=C$ will consist of more than one straight line. For instance $(y/t)^2=1$ consists of two lines: $y=t$ and $y=-t$.